# define dynamic key in initialState in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js, frontend

I have a e-commerce website and every user has shopping cart and handle this with redux and redux persist to store in local storage. I want to handle multiple account in one computer and If a user has two account he can switch between account and and the data related to each account get shown, my problem is how to handle multi account on one system , each account has id. I want to define this structure for initial state:

```
 const initialState = {
    [userId]:{
        cart:[]
  }
```

but I got error

for login I handle this with next-auth and I define this reducer for get Id as user log in.

```
addUserId: async (state, action) => {   //here I receive userId
      const session = await getSession();
      console.log(session);
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your initial state object does not have a defined property, you could start with an empty `initialState` object. When you have data to hydrate your state you can dynamically add `[userId]` properties to state in your reducer. But, when doing so you must initialize that property with an empty object first before assigning the value `{ cart:[] }`. See the [example in the docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers#updating-nested-data) under the text that says: **Immer does not automatically create nested objects or arrays for you - you have to create them yourself.**